# how I can count the number of positive value in each column?

Tags: pyspark

how  I can count the number of positive value in each column?

```
col1       col2       col3
5           6           7
-4          -8         7
1            -4       5
-4           -2        -1
```

output:

```
positives
3
1
2
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following way:

1- make it true , false

2-convert true ,false to 1 ,0

3-count 1s

```
sum3=average_monthly_trend.select(average_monthly_trend['col1']>0,average_monthly_trend['col2']>0,average_monthly_trend['col31']>0)

display(sum3.select([col(c).cast("integer") for c in sum3.columns]).withColumn('sum',sum(F.col(x) for x in sum3.columns)))
```